# How to filter results in listbox (VB)?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, ms-access, visual-studio-2012

I'm using visual studio, and I'm using a column from a database as DataSource and DisplayMember. So, the listbox I have on my form has a list of Names found in my database. In this same database (Microsoft Access Database 2003), I have a column called Date. I want the listbox to only show the Names corresponding to today's date (the date is in number form; only the day of the month (1 to 31). I can used Today.Day on vb to check today's day of month). Please help!

Comment: When you fetch the data from your database, adjust your sql query to only return rows where the date is for today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your listbox's DataSource should be

```
SELECT [Name] FROM MyTable WHERE [Date] = Day(GetDate());
```

You may have to change that to

```
SELECT [Name] FROM MyTable WHERE [Date] = Day(Now());
```

In the first case, that will work on SQL Server.  In the second case, that will work in VBA.  I wasn't quite clear on where this was run based on your question.

Also, just a suggestion moving forward.  Avoid "Reserved words" in field names.  For instance, Date is a reserved word.  When you use it as a field name and try to reference it in a query, you *must* enclose it in brackets or it won't work.  It's more of a hassle than it's worth.  What I do is call date fields "MyDate" or "StDate" or something, and then I never have to worry about tripping over brackets.  Same with Name, which is also a reserved word.

Comment: Neither worked! I want to edit the properties of the listbox so that it only shows the names of date now. I'm visual basic, and the semicolon you put doesn't work for this language btw, so if I have to put it in the Access Database then tell me